# WPF: How can I see where does the app freeze while the background commands are done?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, visual-studio-2019

I have a strange (beginner) situation. I started develop an **asynchronous** application which communicates with external devices via a serial port.

The gui and methods looks good. I can communicate with a device on the serial port well for the first  'test - lap**'. But when I execute the same command in the same application (Visual Studio debug mode myapplication not restarted) for a second time, **the app freezes somewhere**. I cant find the affected line/part/method etc....

Further strange experience: when I leave the app in this freeze stage for a long enough time, once the VS dropped an Exception (after half an hour or little bit more).

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Transition into COM context 0x16057d0 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: System call failed.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100 (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)). This is typically because the COM context 0x16057d0 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else.

Releasing the interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0x1605888). This may cause corruption or data loss.

To avoid this problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for context transition, until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.'
```

Additionally, the commands were sent in the background to the serial port, but the gui and / the code does not execute as in the first lap. Yes, *I use async / await Task.Run(() => way* to try avoid the GUI freeze. And when my tasks are done, I close the port for unexpected hidden behavior. The request and core-logic requires closing the serial port.

When I build the code, the compiler does not indicate an error.

*I tried to use the Debug mode Breakpoints and step into mode* without success. In the other words, my app runs in debug mode and sent some code/ received response well, but for more manual test(lap) in the same app( not closed/terminated) something is stuck or freezes or does not respond, and I want to find exactly where... :(

So, **can someone advise** something on how can I find the root cause (line) of my problem? I am aware of that it is quite hard to answer this question without an example, however the code is complex. Therefore, I would like your help/ advice.

Comment: If you can post a pared down version of the code, not only would that be of use to potential answerers, it might actually help sort what and where something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the app with my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension. It may help you visualize what code is executed and where it hangs.